# ARSession runs but without configuration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit

When I run my `ARSession` with `ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration` the `sceneView.session` property doesn't seem to hold on to the configuration. This is my code

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Create a session configuration
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()

    configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal

    // Run the view's session
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}
```

I put a breakpoint on `sceneView.session.run(configuration)` and it gave me the following

```
po sceneView.session
<ARSession: 0x1c83c8520 currentFrame=0x0 timestamp=0.000000 configuration=(null)>
```

Note: `configuration=(null)`

I'm later trying to access `sceneView.session.currentFrame` but it gives me nil, so I assume the above to be the issue.

I'm running it on an iPad Pro 2017, it does support `ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration`, and I've also tried only using `ARSessionConfiguration` but that gives me the same thing.

Has anyone else experienced this? It kind of looks like an ARKit bug right now, since my code is taken straight from the docs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. And looks like ARSession doesn't runs immediately. I solver it by using a short delay:

```
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { [weak sceneView] in
        guard let cameraTransform = sceneView?.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform else { return }
        /* now you can use cameraTransform */
    }
```

After 0.2 - 0.5 seconds, session starts to determine current frame properly. But before first using of frame you should wait this short time. I hided those 0.5 second with animation of "opening camera", so user won't see this delay.